# Can't send file correct URI using FileProvider

Tags: java, android, android-fileprovider

I'm creating a file with this path

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/package.apk");
```

then I'm trying to send it using this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(UpdateActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
Log.d("uri",FileProvider.getUriForFile(UpdateActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".provider", file).toString());
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

my android manifest is

```
<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

and the `provider_paths`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

After running code I'm getting `There was a problem parsing the package` error but if I open the file using file manager from path `Android/my.package.name/files/package.apk` it's parsing so the `URI` I'm sending is incorrect then I tried to print it and the result is

```
content://my.package.name.provider/files/package.apk
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` on the `Intent`. As it stands, the `Uri` is valid, but the installer has no rights to access its content.

Also note that the stock Android installer only supports `content` schemes as of Android 7.0. Older Android devices are limited to `file`.

Comment: thanks but I'm getting that error again in package installer

Comment: oh it's solved I was using `setFlags()` after adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION`